# Druid query does not return case Insensitive results for count aggregation

Tags: count, aggregate-functions, resultset, case-insensitive, druid

Ideally, I need to get the count of how many times "London" is used in the city name. But the query returns different values for "london" and "London" and "LoNdOn" and so on.
I have tried using Case Insensitive as an option, but it doesn't give me the required result.

Here's my query,

```
 {
"queryType": "topN",
"dataSource": "wikiticker",
"dimension":"cityName",
"granularity": "ALL",
"metric": "count",
"threshold": 10,
"filter":
        { 
            "type": "search",
            "dimension": "cityName",
            "query": {
                "type": "insensitive_contains",
                "value": "london",                  
                 }
             }, 
"aggregations": [
        {
             "type": "longSum",
              "name": "count",
             "fieldName": "count"
         }  
       ],
 "intervals": ["2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z/2016-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"]
 }
```

And here's my result :

```
     [ {
     "timestamp" : "2015-09-12T00:46:58.771Z",
      "result" : [ {
         "count" : 21,
         "cityName" : "London"
        }, 
        {
          "count" : 10,
          "cityName" : "New London"
        }, 
        {
           "count" : 3,
           "cityName" : "london"
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "cityName" : "LoNdon"
        }, 
        {
             "count" : 1,
             "cityName" : "LondOn"
         } ]
      } ]
```

I should get something like:

```
        [ {
            "timestamp" : "2015-09-12T00:46:58.771Z",
            "result" : [ {
            "count" : 26,
            "cityName" : "London"
           }, 
           {
             "count" : 10,
             "cityName" : "New London"
           }  ]
       } ]
```

Comment: So now insensitive_contains is getting me the values i need irrespective of the case the search Keyword is provided in, But i now have to count all the values with similar words but different cases together and not seperately

Answer (score 1):

Use the filtered aggregator:

> A filtered aggregator wraps any given aggregator, but only aggregates the values for which the given dimension filter matches.

```
{
  "type" : "filtered",
  "filter" : {
             "type" : "search",
             "dimension" : cityName,
             "query": {
                      "type":"contains",
                      "value":"london"
                      }          
             },
  "aggregator" : {
                 "type": "count",
                 "name": "Total Count of the Name London"
                 }
}
```

**References**

- [Druid Documentation: Filtered Aggregator](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.2/querying/aggregations.html#filtered-aggregator)